# MongoDB: Using $sample with C# driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to express the following query using the MongoDB C# driver (2.4.4):

```
db.media.aggregate({ $sample: { size: 1 }})
```

This what I have so far:

```
BsonDocument sample = new BsonDocument
{
    { "$sample", new BsonDocument { { "size", 1 } } }
};
MongoBlob mongoBlob = await _collection
    .Aggregate()
    .Group<MongoBlob>(sample)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

I cannot put the `sample` to `.Aggregate(AggregateOptions options = null)` and putting it into the `.Group(...)` is obviously wrong. There is also no any like a `.Sample()` method.

Please, help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply,

```
var randEl = await collection.AsQueryable().Sample(1).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Do not forget add

```
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe it should be

```
MongoBlob mongoBlob = await _collection
    .Aggregate()
    .Sample(1)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

If this doesn't work then let me know. Don't have windows system up right now to confirm

**Edit (7-AUG):**

Turns out its not that simple. The sample method doesn't exists in current driver. The classes which handle this are `internal` so no straight forward way to inherit. So worked out a solution based on reflection and a hack. Where you add a Stage to the pipeline and then edit it through reflection. Below is a working sample of my demo code

using System;
    using MongoDB.Bson;
    using MongoDB.Driver;
    using System.Reflection;

```
namespace TestMongo
{
    public static class MainClass
    {
        static IMongoClient _client;
        static IMongoDatabase _database;

        public static IAggregateFluent<BsonDocument> Sample(this IAggregateFluent<BsonDocument> agg, int count){
            var new_agg = agg.Skip(10);
            var stage =new_agg.Stages[new_agg.Stages.Count-1];
            var newDoc = new BsonDocument { 
                { "$sample", new BsonDocument {
                        {"size", count}
                    } } 
            };
            stage.GetType().GetField("_document"
             , BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                 .SetValue(stage, newDoc);
            return new_agg;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            _client = new MongoClient();
            _database = _client.GetDatabase("jobs");

            var col = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("results");

            var agg = col.Aggregate().Sample(1);

            var data = agg.FirstOrDefault();
            data = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also expect something like that, but there is no `.Sample()` method.

Comment: Let me check on system and get back to you

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, do you know if it's possible just to run a raw query via C# driver? Like: `await _collection.QueryAsync("db.media.aggregate({ $sample: { size: 1 }})");` I don't see a method for that.

Comment: I am not sure of that. I looked at the source code nothing that is obvious which would allow you to do that

Answer (score 1):

```
var sample = new BsonDocument 
{ 
    { 
        "$sample", new BsonDocument 
        { 
            {"size", 1000} 
        } 
    } 
};

var samples = _collection.Aggregate().AppendStage(new BsonDocumentPipelineStageDefinition<MyType, MyType>(sample));
return await samples.ToListAsync();
```