# Sample a random document from a mongoDB database in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

Trying to grab a random document from a database collection (named 'users_coll' in this example) with 100 documents inside of it.  After grabbing one document, I want to take the "_id" field from that document, and save it for later.

I'm a bit confused about the "proper" way to get the document.  I'm gathering that '$sample' is what I want to use, but I'm having a hard time correctly formatting the query and extracting the correct info.

This is what I have now:

```
var filter = "{ $sample: { size: 1 } }";
var sample_user = users_coll.Find(filter).ToBsonDocument();
var id = sample_user["_id"];
```

this essentially finds nothing.

I've also tried using:

```
var sample_user = users_coll.Aggregate({ $sample: { size: 1 } });
var id = sample_user["_id"];
```

but C# doesn't want to compile that one.

I expect/want the find/aggregate output to be a single random document from the database, and I expect/want the "id" result to be the "_id" field from the gathered document.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45530988/1859959 looks like the sample is not that straight forward in the "right" way. It's not made public in a sense, just for the `AsQueryable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this package

```
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
```

Try like this:

```
users_coll.AsQueryable().Sample(20);
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.